# Caliburn.Micro: Action of Button inside ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, action, caliburn.micro

I try to use the `Caliburn.Micro` framework to optimize my current `WPF` application following the `MVVM` scheme. Setting the action of a button can normally achieved very without any problem just by setting the `x:Name` value of the button and adding a function with the same name in the view model. Things (at least it seems to me so) get more complicated when you try to do this inside a `ControlTemplate`. My current approach looks like this code:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Chains">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <StackPanel>
                <ContentControl/>
                <ItemsPresenter />
                <Button Content="+" x:Name="AddChain"/>
             </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

But sadly, the `AddChain` method of the `ViewModel` which corresponds to the `view` in which this code is placed is never called.

I think that I have to tell `Caliburn` to use this `ViewModel` and not a `ViewModel` which corresponds to the `ControlTemplate`. Is this correct? How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the `cal:Bind.Model` attached property to your view model:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Chains">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl" xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
            <StackPanel cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}">
                <ContentControl/>
                <ItemsPresenter />
                <Button Content="+" x:Name="AddChain"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more examples under the CaliburnMicro. I had the same issue with buttons created dynamically under a ItemSource. MM8 answer answer is helpfull and shall be enough, but if you looking to know more or for other applications have a read through will help you.
[CaliburnMicro ActionDocs](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions) - See Section "Action Parameters"

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).